# Javascript Get Array with Object Value

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I have JSON that I need to search. I am using the following code to retreive the data I need:

```
function loadJson(){
$.getJSON("json/levels.json", function(json) {
    var level = $('#levelselect').val();
    $('#sometextbox').val(json.level[0]["1"].Title);
    $('#othertextbox').val(json.level[0]["1"].Body);
    }
}
```

Here is the JSON I am using.

```
{
  "level": [
    {
      "1": {
        "Title": "My First Title",
        "Body": "My First Body"
      }
    },
    {
      "2": {
        "Title": "My Second Title",
        "Body": "My Second Body"
      }
    }
]
}
```

I need to be able to use a javascript object in place of the key index number:

```
var myNumber = 1;
json.level[0][myNumber];
```

I have tried this with: 
    var myNumber = 1;
    json.level[0][{myNumber}];
But this didn't work as I just get an undefined error.

Comment: `level[0]['1']` and `level[1]['2']` but that's very very silly structure... you should absolutely change the JSON format.

Comment: The syntax in `[{myNumber}]` makes no sense : an object has a key-value structure : `[{key : value}]` is probably what you meant... ?

Comment: Why is `level` an array? Also the example JSON is malformed.

Comment: doesn't look like you're closing your array either "]"

Comment: I cannot change the format of this JSON. It fits into a larger piece of software and this structure has to be kept as it. myNumber is a number I want to use in place of "1" to get specific objects. Hope this helps, I've amended my code.

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried this with: `var myNumber = 1; json.level[0][{myNumber}];`

Just omit the curly braces and use the `myNumber` variable directly in the [property accessor brackets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors):

```
var myNumber = 1;
json.level[0][myNumber];
```

I wonder however why using them gave you an `undefined` error, not a syntax error. You don't use a browser that supports ES6 shorthand property literals, do you?

Comment: Hmm.. strange, I got it to work by parsing myNumber as an int.. Rest of your code worked fine, thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by parsing as an int? `myNumber = 1` is already a number.

Comment: I was getting by taking a value from a textbox input : var myNumber = $('#myTextBox').val();